# Higher Accuracy from Optimizer in Python

Tags: python, optimization, gradient, scipy-optimize

I am currently solving an optimization problem to get certain design parameters such that my objective function becomes zero.

As of now, I am getting a solution that is close to the result I am expecting but I want to increase the number of iterations (or whatever) of the optimizer so that it iterates or solves till my objective function value is below a certain limit.

How do I give this constraint in Python? I am using the BFGS method for optimization.

```
results = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj, DesVar, method='BFGS')
```

Here, obj is my objective function and DesVar is the design variable (an array).

Do recommend if you feel there are any other optimization methods that can make this possible if there isn't one for this one. (Looking only for gradient-based methods)

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Typically this is done by lowering the tolerance. But since you have no code here it's impossible to say whether that will work.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is OK to upload the code here. It is for my project. Could you tell more specifically what you're looking for in it?

Comment: Couple of thoughts: 1) minimize() doesn't have a mode where it continues until the objective function goes below some threshold. It continues until it finds a local minimum in the function. 2) If you're not sure why your solver is terminating, I suggest looking at the message attribute of the result for why it terminated. 3) Some solvers can solve problems which other solvers cannot. I'd suggest trying a [different solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

Comment: 4) You may be having a problem with local minima. There are a few approaches you can use if this is the problem, such as [scipy.optimize.brute](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html#scipy.optimize.brute), or [scipy.optimize.basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping), both of which have protections against getting stuck in local minima at the cost of compute time.